# UE4: CodeSign Failed, get-task-allow entitlement doesn't match

Tags: arkit, unreal-engine4, code-signing-entitlements

I have a very simple Unreal project which is being packaged without the plugin Apple ARKit. When I enable ARKit, it gives me an error

> Provisioning Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for
> the get-task-allow entitlement. Error: CodeSign Failed

It a blueprint only project for now, so there is not xcworkspace. Engine: UE4.27plus.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you checked “For Distribution” in the Project settings.

Had the same error and it was gone after ticking the option.

[For Distribution Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/349oo.png)